# IIS ARR NTLM ntlmssp_negotiate

Tags: windows, iis, load-balancing, iis-8, arr

**This is NTLM authentication:**

```
Get / -> HTTP 401
Get / ntlmssp_negotiate -> HTTP 401 ntlmssp_challenge
Get / ntlmssp_auth -> HTTP 200
```

My problem is that `ntlmssp_negotiate` is not pass trough

**Expected Behavior:**

```
Request
. 
Response


loadbalancer:80 Get /
node1:80 Get /
.
node1:80 HTTP 401 Unauthorized
loadbalancer:80 HTTP 401 Unauthorized

loadbalancer:80 Get / ntlmssp_negotiate 
node1:80 Get / ntlmssp_negotiate
.
node1:80 HTTP 401 ntlmssp_challenge
loadbalancer:80 HTTP 401 ntlmssp_challenge

loadbalancer:80 Get / ntlmssp_auth 
node1:80 Get / ntlmssp_auth 
.
node1:80 HTTP 200
loadbalancer:80 HTTP 200
```

**Actual Behavior:**

```
Request 
.
Response 

loadbalancer:80 Get /
node1:80 Get /
.
node1:80 HTTP 401 Unauthorized
loadbalancer:80 HTTP 401 Unauthorized

loadbalancer:80 Get / ntlmssp_negotiate 
. 
loadbalancer:80 HTTP 401 ntlmssp_challenge

loadbalancer:80 Get / ntlmssp_auth 
node1:80 Get / ntlmssp_auth 
.
node1:80 HTTP 401 Unauthoized
loadbalancer:80 HTTP 401 Unauthoized
```

As you can see loadbalancer is not forwarding `ntlmssp_negotiate` to its nodes. It seem to me that is resolved by loadbalancer it selft without forwarding.

**Configuration:**

```
IIS 8.5
ARR 3.0
WIN 2012 R2 Standard
```

But this is not happening on configuration 2.

**Configuration 2:**

```
IIS 10
ARR 3.0
WIN 10 Enterprise
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there was something in memory after installing ARR ...

after

**c:\> iisreset**

everything works fine.